# Как решить проблему с StackOverflow ecxeption?

Tags: c#, selenium

Есть рекурсивная функция

```
 public static void check()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var textmsg = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[last()]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span[1]/span")).Text;
                string textmsgS = Convert.ToString(textmsg).ToLower();
                Console.WriteLine(textmsgS);
                if (textmsgS == "чек")
                {
                    var txtMensagem = By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]");
                    webDriver.SetText(txtMensagem, "кеч");


                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                    webDriver.FindElement(txtMensagem).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                check();

            }
        }
    }
```

Собственно программа вылетает с ошибкой process is terminating due to stackoverflowexception. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: То есть, если у вас возникает ошибка, вы вызываете эту ф-ю снова? А где у вас точка выхода, раз это рекурсивная ф-я? Проверьте, попадаете ли вы в блок catch

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar Да, возникает именно когда попадает в блок catch, точнее даже когда раз 10-20, а не с первого захода. Ну и туда попадает соответственно. Точка входа в main, там ведутся подготовительные действия, далее просто вызывается эта самая рекурсивная функция: check();.

Comment: Уберите вызов `check()` --- не будет рекурсии, не будет `StackOverflowException`

Comment: Ужаснейший код и ужаснейший подход к решению задачи (я про селениум). По поводу вопроса - у вас нету логического завершения программы. Сейчас примерно у вас происходит следующее: "работаю"->"вызываю себя заново"->"работаю"->"вызываю себя заново" и так по кругу. Зачем вам тут вызов повторно этого метода, если у вас цикл сделает повтор? Зачем вам тут цикл. если вы не выходите из него? Убирайте из `catch` вызов, делайте не знаю, счетчик какой то и в коде, когда счетчик будет скажем == 3, делайте `return`, ибо если за 3 захода не получили нужное - все, дальше не получите.